# Identify LCD and driver and touch pannel

Tags: pi-4, driver, lcd

I'm going through my box of bits to start a new project and having trouble with an LCD screen. When connected to the pi4 it doesn't fit the screen. Thing is the no signal screen also doesn't fit when I disconnect the pi... so I'm assuming that the driver believes the native res is different to that of the screen

The touch screen digitiser has tp-r070 4 2 written on it what driver do I need for this 4 pin ribbon connector

The LCD driver has GJX.58HD written on it using UART chip GM8284DD

And a driver chip TSUMU58VHN-1

The driver board has

- 4 pin connector with 5v 5v GND GND
- 3 pin connector with 5v out, IR, GND
- hdmi in
- LCD out
- 4 pin pad for SDA SCL GND NC

What would be needed to instruct the driver board to set a lower resolution I assume the circuit needs modifying to tell the uart chip 800 x 480 is native or is it firmware

Hopefully these pictures say a thousand words.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/bVHwkAn3jim9jobV6

I've found the data sheet for the GM8284DD but i cant read it
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809111820_CORPRO-GM8284DD_C245023.pdf

from looking at it it looks like the uart supports  VGA，SVGA，SXGA（dual pixel），UXGA（dual pixel）

I cant find anything on the TSUMU58VHN-1

after playing with it in windows using nvidia control pannel to create custom resolutions I can see it works at 1024 x 576 CVt think the driver is scaling it and worked well at 800 x 480 but the driver board seems to try to switch to 384 x 288 for any resolution the pi uses, the controller does say its 1024 x 768 (native) to windows, linux and raspberry pi hence why the pi is only showing part of the screen.

after googling 800 x 480 lcd's I found this

[image: aliexpress product]

whats the best approach to sort this with the raspberry pi and the controller I have, how easy is it to modify the controller? i've tried
hdmi safe and
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 in the boot

Thanks

Comment: the "no signal screen" does not use a driver

Comment: there is absolutely no excuse for posting a picture with flash glare

Comment: The "no signal" screen is generated by the driver chip is it not? perhaps a better word is controller to prevent the confusion between software driver and LCD driver

Comment: you are absolutely correct ...  I was thinking software driver ... silly me